How to use width of CSS Grid track for another elements margin?
I use a CSS grid with named tracks for my layout.
[full] [breakout] [content] [breakout] [full].
This way i can use breakout and full to breakout from my default content width.
This is working very well.
I also added breakout-left, breakout-right and full-left, full-right to breakout only to one side.
In my design the nested content usually should still be aligned with the horizontal center of viewport.
Example (tailwind):
<section class='breakout-left'>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <div>IMAGE</div>
    <div>CONTENT</div>
  </div>
</section>

The image breaks out correctly. But the center of the grid won't be the center of the screen. So the image won't align with the horizontal center of viewport
See example of sections and center lines here:
https://codepen.io/danpii/pen/qBeZQZW
CSS from pen:
/*

layout Grid

 */

:root {

    --content-max-width: 88rem; 
    --breakout-max-width: 104rem; 
    --breakout-width: calc((var(--breakout-max-width) - var(--content-max-width)) / 2);

    --gap: clamp(0.675rem, 4vw, 3rem); /* 10.8px -> 48px*/
    --full: minmax(var(--gap), 1fr);
    --content: min(100% - (var(--gap) * 2), var(--content-max-width));
    --breakout: minmax(0, var(--breakout-width));

/*@inspiration*/
/*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c13gpBrnGEw*/
/*https://smolcss.dev/#smol-breakout-grid*/
/*https://ryanmulligan.dev/blog/layout-breakouts/*/

@layer base {
    .content-grid{

        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns:
    [full-start full-left-start] var(--full)
    [breakout-start breakout-left-start] var(--breakout)
    [content-start breakout-right-start full-right-start] var(--content) [content-end breakout-left-end full-left-end]
    var(--breakout) [breakout-end breakout-right-end]
    var(--full) [full-end full-right-end];
    }

    
    .content-grid > *,
    .full > *{
        grid-column: content;
    }


 
    .content-grid > .breakout {
        grid-column: breakout;
    }

    .content-grid > .breakout-left {
        grid-column: breakout-left;
    }

    .content-grid > .breakout-right {
        grid-column: breakout-right;
    }

    .content-grid > .full {
        grid-column: full;

    }

    .content-grid > .full-left {
        grid-column: full-left;
    }

    .content-grid > .full-right {
        grid-column: full-right;
    }
  
  .flow > *:where(:not(:first-child)) {
        margin-top: 1.5rem
    }
}


New idea: I would like to use just breakout, but then push the content back into the [content] column via margin-right.
<section class='breakout'>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <div>IMAGE</div>
    <div>CONTENT - add margin-right to align with content</div>
  </div>
</section>

Those are the relevant css variables:
    --content-max-width: 88rem; /*1408px*/   
    --breakout-max-width: 104rem; /*1664px*/
    --breakout-width: calc((var(--breakout-max-width) - var(--content-max-width)) / 2);

    --gap: clamp(0.675rem, 4vw, 3rem); /* 10.8px -> 48px*/
    --full: minmax(var(--gap), 1fr);
    --content: min(100% - (var(--gap) * 2), var(--content-max-width));
    --breakout: minmax(0, var(--breakout-width));

I can't figure out how to calculate the correct track width of my breakout column to use it as margin-right. Especially since --full uses 1fr, which can't be used in css calc().
My favourite solution would be CSS only, creating a new css variable e.g. --breakout-track-size.
Any ideas?
